# Geoserver Rendering Error

Tags: geoserver, rendering, geowebcache

For specific zoom level Geoserver cannot rendered my map anymore. Following error notification is shown:

> at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
>       at org.geotools.renderer.label.GlyphVectorProcessor.process(GlyphVectorProcessor.java:50)
>       at org.geotools.renderer.label.GlyphVectorProcessor$Curved.process(GlyphVectorProcessor.java:88)
>       at org.geotools.renderer.label.LabelCacheImpl.paintLineLabelsWithLetterConflict(LabelCacheImpl.java:796)
>       at org.geotools.renderer.label.LabelCacheImpl.paintLabel(LabelCacheImpl.java:562)
>       at org.geotools.renderer.label.LabelCacheImpl.paintLabels(LabelCacheImpl.java:518)
>       at org.geotools.renderer.label.LabelCacheImpl.end(LabelCacheImpl.java:466)
>       at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.java:871)
>       at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:581)

Can anyone help to figure out what is going on?

Comment: Looks to me like the labels can't be rendered at that zoom level.

Comment: Turn logging up to debug and check the log file then. To fully debug we will also need the data and style